# nginx in kubernetes does not redirect for one app, but does for another

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have the following deployment yaml files:

```
foo.yaml:

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: foo-ingress
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
            rewrite ^(/apps/foo)$ $1/ redirect;
spec:
    rules:
    - host: myhost
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /apps/foo/(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: foo-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

```
bar.yaml:

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: bar-ingress
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
            rewrite ^(/apps/bar)$ $1/ redirect;
spec:
    rules:
    - host: myhost
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /apps/bar/(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: foo-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

I applied each file with

```
kubectl apply -f foo.yaml

kubectl apply -f bar.yaml
```

The problem is that the redirection from /apps/foo to /apps/foo/ (adding the extra slash) works fine. The redirection from /apps/bar does not work. I get a 404.

I opened the generated nginx.conf in the ingress pod, and it's a bit of a mess. I have the following (removed irrelevant parts):

```
    location ~* "^/apps/foo/(.*)" {
       rewrite ^(/apps/foo)$ $1/ redirect;
    }
    location ~* "^/apps/bar/(.*)" {
       rewrite ^(/apps/bar)$ $1/ redirect;
    }
    location ~* "^/" {
       ...
       rewrite ^(/apps/foo)$ $1/ redirect;
    }
```

As you can see, the redirection is added both under the / matching (where it works) and also in the more specific matching, where it makes no sense (as it will never get there, given that without a / the rule will not match).

What am I doing wrong in the overall approach? why is the ingress controller adding redirection only to one url?

Comment: Some time ago, I also struggled with paths in ingress controller under one hostname. I spend so much time on it, but I couldn't quite figure out why it didn't work. What I found is best to use separate domains (or subdomains) for each ingress controller you deploy. If your K8s is localhost, or you don't want to set up domain names especially for this then you should definitely check out [nip.io](https://nip.io/). It allows you to map any IP address to a hostname. I don't know what's your use case but maybe that'll help you.

Comment: Hello @StefanoBorini. Have you tried to follow [this example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)?